# NSEntityDescription Not found

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a `CoreData` database which works on the root view controller. I have a second `UIViewController` of which when I switch to, and use the same exact line to fetch `NSEntityDescription`, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Channel''

I am doing that as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Channel" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

The error hits at the `NSEntityDescription *entity` line. How is this possible if the line works on another `UIViewController`?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is suggesting that the `ManagedObjectContext` have a problem.

Are you passing your `ManagedObjectContext` from your first view to the second (if not try it)

If this doesn't work can you post the code where you're assigning `self.context`

---

You mean code like this one in your `appDelegate` in the `awakeFromNib` method:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[self.navigationController topViewController];
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

You need the second line to pass the actual `managedObjectContext`

You can put that second line in your `firstView` like this:

```
//secondViewController creation here
secondViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController
                                         animated:YES];
```

Of course you need to set up the necessary `@property`.
In doing so from `UIViewController` to `UIViewController` starting from the `appDelegate` you will be passing a reference to that instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`.

---

[UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is there if you need more information.
Just make sure that when you make the assignment the `IBOutlet` are set and that your `NSManagedObject` have been created.

> An array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface.
>       @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers

Comment: You're right. I am not passing `ManagedObjectContext` to the second view. I pass it to the first view from my `AppDelegate` as follows: ` NowViewController *nowViewController = (NowViewController *) [self.navigationController topViewController];`. How would I do the same to pass it to my second view? I want to try to do it using `AppDelegate` but how would I do so? I can't use `topViewController` since it's not at the top of the stack.

Comment: I am using a UITabBarController though. So I am never "pushing" the view controller myself. So where would I create the secondViewController and pass that to it? And how would I create the secondViewcontroller in this case? Is there any way to do it without having to create the UITabBarController programatically?  Thanks

Comment: OK even simpler, at some point in your code you are setting the UITabBarController array's of UIViewController. So you must be creating all your UIViewController at that point. Give all your UIViewController a reference to your NSManagedObjectContext at that time. There is an other way, but it's less pretty.

Comment: problem is I created it with interface builder. Do I have to create the tab bar programatically to get it working?

Comment: You have an outlet to it? You can acess the array of UIViewContreller by it if you are not created them in code.

Comment: yes in my AppDelegate. In this case, would I pass the ManagedObject over there? This means i have to create a SecondViewController object before it opens. Is this fine?

Comment: it depends on how your code is construct. If all is done in interface builder, that you have all set your UIViewController for the tabBar in IB (is that possible... probably, I always do that part in code). IF ALL IS DONE IN IB, `awakeFromNib` is the place where your IBOutlet will be set, so you can use them to reach your object.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was to load the NSEntityDescription manually instead of using the convenience method from NSFetchRequest:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest new] autorelease];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```